# How to find and join parallel lines automatically

Tags: autocad, autolisp

i assemble drawings done by many people. Sometimes as they draw over the same road (for example), they dont necessarily produce one seemingly continuous line. Sometimes it's parallel or a bit off.
[image: Here's an example]

The criteria for correction: 2 lines in the same layer, same direction often very close (i can estimate a tolerance)

Do you think there's some command routine or lisp that finds and correct this? Without having to manually select them?

I'm not very familiar with coding so i hope someone clever here can help me out. I have attached the test file.

Thank you sincerely.

Reem.

I tried overkill to at least delete the almost overlapping segments so i can use join but it didnt work